# RTL properties with padding attribute android

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I am working on an android application and provided support for RTL feature in my application. 
Now when I define any marginLeft Property, I define the same marginStart property also on that view to have the same with RTL languages.

If I define margin attribute (margin attribute contains : marginTop, marginLeft, marginRight and marginBottom), so this attribute already contains Left and Right margins, so should I need to define marginStart and marginEnd properties as well on this view, or it'll be automatically work on that.

Please help if anyone have any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

In places you use both marginLeft and marginRight you don't need to add marginStart/marginEnd.
You should use Start/End when you define one side only.

Answer (score 0):

- If your app only supports API ≥ 17, replace all the layout_marginLeft/layout_marginReft/paddingLeft/paddingRight or any other Left and Right layout property with Start and End equivalent. For example android:paddingLeft will be replaced with android:paddingStart.
- If your app supports API<17 then instead of replacing the Left and Right layout properties, add their Start and End layout property equivalent alongside.